# Passing value from site to iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to insert a calculator from another website into my website through iframe. There are dozens of products on my website, so I want this calculator to get price values automatically (now you have to manually change it). It should take the price value from the page and send it to the calculator, so the numbers are correct. Is it possible to automate this, if so how?

The code looks similar to this:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.otherwebsite.com/calculator.php?layout=layout2&amp;clientid=client1&amp;price=3399&amp;action=0&amp;width=350&amp;height=150" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:0; overflow:hidden; width:350px; height:150px;" ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was not possible to do with Simple IFrame Passing the GET Values.

You can try using PHP Form POST & GET method To retrieve the value or You can try with PHP CURL (If the another website is supported or allowed that action.)